# Linear system on $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am not sure about it : this is a probably a really naive question. I saw in a lecture note the author talking about the linear system $ |L - p_1 - p_2 - p_3|$ where $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ is a line and the $p_i$ are points. Since $L - p_1 - p_2 - p_3$ is not a divisor I don't understand what does it mean. Is this all the rational map $f \in \mathbb C(\mathbb P^2)$ such that $f$ has a pole at $L$ and a zero at the $p_i$ ? 
If this is the case, then such map should be $f/l$ with $l$ a linear polynomial which is zero on $L$. The points were assumed non-collinear, so there is no such $f$ and so $|L - p_1 - p_2 - p_3| = \emptyset$. Does this make sense ? Am I mistaken somewhere ? Thanks a lot for any comments !

Comment: That does look odd. Pole and zeroes always occurs in codimension one. Perhaps the variety studied in your notes is not $\mathbb P^2$, but $\mathbb P^2$ blown up at the three points $p_1, p_2, p_3$?

Comment: I agree also that $|D|$ makes only sense for $D$ a divisor. This is written explicitely that the variety is in $\mathbb P^2$. The notes are here : https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf page 13, exercise 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of $|2L - p_1 - p_2 - p_3|$ as the sublinear system of $|2L|$ on $\mathbb P^2$ consisting of all quadrics on $\mathbb P^2$ that vanish at $p_1, p_2, p_3$. This is a linear system, but it is not a complete linear system.

Let's do a dimension count. The linear system of quadrics on $\mathbb P^2$ has dimension 5, so after imposing the constraint that the quadrics pass through $p_1, p_2, p_3$, you end up with a linear system of dimension 2. Thus your linear system defines a rational map from $\mathbb P^2$ to $\mathbb P^2$. If the three points are $[1:0:0]$, $[0:1:0]$, $[0:0:1]$, for example, then the equation for this rational map is
$$ [x_0 : x_1: x_2] \mapsto [x_1x_2:x_0x_2:x_0x_1].$$
In your notes, this map is called the elementary quadratic transformation, but I have heard people calling it a Cremona transformation.

Note that if $\pi : Bl_{(p_1, p_2, p_3)}\mathbb P^2 \to \mathbb P^2$ is the blow-up of $\mathbb P^2$ at $p_1, p_2, p_3$, then $\pi^\star |2L-p_1-p_2-p_3|$ is the complete linear system $|2L-E_1-E_2-E_3|$, where $E_i$ is the exceptional divisor above the point $p_i$. My guess would be that the sections of $\pi^\star |2L-p_1-p_2-p_3|$ define a morphism from $Bl_{(p_1, p_2, p_3)}\mathbb P^2$ to $\mathbb P^2$ but $|2L-p_1-p_2-p_3|$ only defines a rational map from $\mathbb P^2 $ to $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: Your guess is absolutely correct.

Comment: @bertram Thanks for your comment! I think I understand this thing now - it's a blow-up of $[1:0:0], [0:1:0], [0:0:1]$ followed by a contraction of the strict transforms of the lines $x_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$. What a nice construction!

Comment: Yes, that description is again exactly correct. Finally I will comment that this is indeed an *example* of a Cremona transformation, but that term means something more general, namely *any* birational self-map of $\mathbf P^2$. The amazing fact is that the group of all Cremona transformations is generated by projective linear automorphisms together with this one map.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome.